# Apptainer installation with use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, singularity-container, apptainer

I am extremely happy user of Windows OS 11 who needs to use Apptainer in my developer work. I am considering two options of apptainer installation/use in Windows:

- using Git/VirtualBox/Vagrant/Vagrant Manager
- using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL Ubuntu) that is provided in Microsoft Store apps.

I would prefer to use the second option, especially since according to documentation : "Manage Docker containers with improved performance and startup times". Official Apptainer documentation mention to use WSL and follow the Linux instructions, but I can imagine that there is always a catch.

Do you have any recommendations for that? For example, do I need to install WSL in a special way (separate disk partition)? Please share your experience if you are using this approach?